# Firebase's SET method isn't working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using **firebase** and I wrote a simple function in Javascript to SET and UPDATE data.

```
function setLastOnline(userID, InOut){
    var dbLastonline = firebase.database().ref().child("lastonline");
    if (InOut) {
        dbLastonline.child(userID).set({
            "isConnected":true,
            "connectedby":"web",
            "lastIn":firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
            "lastOut":0
        });
    } else {
        dbLastonline.child(userID).update({
            "isConnected":false,
            "connectedby":"web",
            "lastOut":firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        });
    }
}
```

When I call the function to perform the SET method, nothing happens... No data in database and no error code...

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            setLastOnline(user.uid, true);
        }
      }
```

But when I call the same function to perform the UPDATE, everything works fine.

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            setLastOnline(user.uid, false);
            firebase.auth().signOut();
        }`
     }`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't immediately see what's wrong with this code. Can you create a jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Add a print before your **set** call just to be sure your code is running as expected...

Comment: I've test everything. The code is performing as desired but isn't recording in database. And in my tests today, I found a firebase's VERBOSE in Chrome console: **[Violation] Avoid using document.write() at line 362 of www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.8/firebase.js**. It appears in the exactly moment of execution  of SET method.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. The above function is correct and works well. The problem was that I called a window.open() shortly after calling setLastOnline(). Like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            setLastOnline(user.uid, true);
            window.open('another_page.php','_self');
        }
      }
```

So the Firebase's execution stops and the VERBOSE in Chrome console (**[Violation] Avoid using document.write() at line 362 of www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.8/firebase.js**) appears.

Regards!

Comment: Good catch! The devil is in the details... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no actual solution given, I thought it would be worth sharing the solution that I was able to piece together.  The solution I pieced together was to use .then to force .set() to run completely before it moves onto loading the next screen. as shown below.

```
firebase.database().ref().child('/churches/' + userName ).set(data).then( function(){     
    window.location = "Homepage.html";
});
```

Since I'm new to programming I don't know how to implement this method into the author's code, however, I believe the code above is what the original code trying to achieve.  If you want to find out how .then works you can look up "promises in javascript".